# best way to check if xml (without file extension) exists

Tags: php, xml, url, file-exists

Unfortunately I can't check it right now, because the XML **(which will be on another server)** is offline. The url to the xml file will look like this: http://url.com:123/category?foo=bar. It comes with no .xml file extension as you can see. I forgot to insert a file check to avoid error messages printing out the url of the xml file.
simple_load_file works fine with that URL, but I'm not sure about file_exists!

Would this work?:

```
if(file_exists('http://url.com:123/category?foo=bar')) { 
$xml = simplexml_load_file('http://url.com:123/category?foo=bar');
//stuff happens here
} else{echo 'Error message';}
```

I'm not sure since file_exists doesn't work with URLs.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As you suspect, [`file_exists()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php) doesn't work with URLs, but [`fopen()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) and [`fclose()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fclose.php) do:

```
if (fclose(fopen("http://url.com:123/category?foo=bar", "r"))) {
    $xml = simplexml_load_file('http://url.com:123/category?foo=bar');
    //stuff happens here
} else {
    echo 'Error message';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not really useful, if you just try to fetch the data to parse it. Especially if the URL you call is a program/script itself. This will just mean that the script is executed twice.

I suggest you fetch the data with `file_get_contents()`, handle/catch the errors and parse the fetched data.

Just blocking the errors:

```
if ($xml = @file_get_contents($url)) {
  $element = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
  ...
}
```

Comment: That makes sense since the XMLs can get rather lenghty. Thank you.